# Is there any setting in spring boot jpa to enable for to fire trigger on db?

Tags: database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, database-trigger, postgresql-9.5

Actually when I insert using query directly using query tool then the trigger is working, but whenever I hit using service save API the trigger is not working.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of this trigger and the query you are running.

Comment: If you have a trigger in the database, then **any** INSERT will fire that trigger, regardless of the tool or application which sent the INSERT statement.